# The energy axis for beta spectrum and Antineutrino spectrum

Tags: radiation, proton-decay

I am trying to plot an antineutrino spectrum and I was wondering whether the x axis has same range of energy values as the beta spectrum? I am taking the range of energy values to be from 0 upto maximum beta decay energy. Can anyone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a $\beta$ decay.
The energy spectrum of the emitted electron may look like this.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Description))</sub>

The total energy of electron and antineutrino ($E_\text{el}+E_\nu$)
is always $E_\text{max}$ (in this example $1.16$ MeV).
Therefore the energy spectrum of the antineutrino will be
the mirror image of the electron's energy spectrum,
with the same $E_\text{max}$.

[image]

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply @Thomas Fritsch. However I have one doubt, to find the complete antineutrino spectra do we have to find the weighted spectra because I have many subplots of antineutrino spectra and I want to find a complete one.